# Why is ansible not setting the seuser properly on this directory?

Tags: centos, ansible

Here is the relevant portion of the ansible file:

```
- name: "Create bond user"
  user:
    user: bond
    shell: /bin/bash

- name: "Allow bond agent to be run"
  sefcontext:
    target: "/home/bond/bond_agent"
    seuser: system_u
    setype: bin_t
    state: present

- name: "Create bond agent directory"
  file:
    path: "/home/bond/bond_agent"
    state: directory
    mode: 0500
    owner: bond
    group: bond

- name: "Copy bond agent binary"
  copy:
    src: bond-agent
    dest: /home/bond/bond_agent/bond-agent
    owner: bond
    group: bond
    mode: 0555

- name: "Copy bond agent config file"
  template:
    src: bond-agent.yml.j2
    dest: /home/bond/bond_agent/bond-agent.yml
    owner: bond
    group: bond
    mode: 0555

- name: "Apply new SELinux file context to /bond_agent directory"
  command: restorecon -irv /home/bond/bond_agent
```

After running the ansible playbook, doing `ls -laZ` on `/home/bond/bond_agent`, I see:

```
dr-x------.  2 bond bond unconfined_u:object_r:bin_t:s0           117 Sep 16 13:21 bond_agent
```

Running `semanage fcontext -l -C` I see:

```
SELinux fcontext                                   type               Context

/home/bond/bond_agent                          all files          system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 
/bond_agent                                      all files          system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 

SELinux Local fcontext Equivalence 

/bond_agent/bond-agent = /bond_agent
bond-agent = bond-agent.yml
```

New to CentOS (CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004) + ansible so I'm not quite sure what's going on or how to solve it.

Comment: It looks like it was set correctly to me. Though I wonder why you run restorecon after setting the context yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include "-F" to restorecon when changing seuser.  restorecon only changes the type by default.